# W3Schools example of PNG clipping Mask in CSS doesn't work locally

Tags: html, css, cors, png, mask

I copy and paste [this code example from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_mask-image) into a HTML file on my local computer.

I also put the required image files in that folder. See the screen shot below for how it renders.

The mask fails to render correctly. I've checked this with Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

[image: Screenshot of W3Schools Example]

The code I'm using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .mask1 {
      -webkit-mask-image: url(w3logo.png);
      mask-image: url(w3logo.png);
      -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
      mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>The mask-image Property</h1>

  <h3>An image with a mask layer image:</h3>
  <div class="mask1">
    <img src="img_5terre.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
  </div>

  <h3>Original image:</h3>
  <img src="img_5terre.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">

</body>

</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of the files in the folder.
[image]

Comment: "_I also put the required image files in that folder._" I suspect you're mistaken. I went to the example link you posted and changed the `url(w3logo.png)` reference to point to a non-existent file, and I got the exact same output your screenshot shows.

Comment: The name of the site is w3schools.com; it has no allegiance or ties to the standards site w3.org. Using W3 to refer to it merely exacerbates the confusion.

Comment: "*W3Schools example ... doesn't work*" - is one of the biggest problems with that site, and why most of us will recommend you to use MDN ([Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org)) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try open your broser console and check if has some error messages about **[CORS policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)**:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

If yes, you need upload the [W3 Logo](https://www.w3schools.com/css/w3logo.png) image bellow to your application server or localhost directory:

[image: W3 Logo]

**Alternative:** Convert the image to a base64. I've used [Base64 Image Encoder](https://www.base64-image.de), but can be anyone.

```css
.mask1 {
  -webkit-mask-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
  mask-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOwAAADeCAYAAAA+YeyyAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAg+klEQVR4nO2dedhd0/XHPy+vqCSIMRISUVQoQlFKDa05ptKiVFtFS2n5abWoVkKFoIa2dFJDa9aaS1tqTE2NIaaqIOYhQQYSMhC/P773yM2be88++0z77HP353neJ8PdZ+/13nPWWXuvvdbaXYMGrUggEADgU8DjwCLAdMeyRCwM9AZ2A27odixMIFAlFgJ6Nf6+uEtBWtALJGAgEKg+cyEobCDgFUFhAwGPCAobCPhBFwSFDQR8IShsIOAJ7wD3Q1DYQMAHdgZeAQj7sIHAPGYDE5BevJexry7gQ+ADFIjxBjAV2BUFQyTla8CY6B9BYQOBeUwAVi2w/58Cu1u0Pxa4rPk/wpQ4ECiHE4GfW7T/HTC6538GhQ0Eimck8DOL9jcB3231QVDYQKBYDgVGWLR/FNil3YdBYQOB4tgZONei/SRge+Cjdg2CwgYCxbAOcL3lNTsAE+MaBIUNBPKnH1qH2ujXLsAjpkZBYQOB/PkbMMii/WGNa4wEhQ0E8uViYDOL9qcBv0naOChsIJAfI4D9LNpfARxtM0A3MApYBXgNPxV4IbRmOAu5xH3jGGANYIprQXKmF7o3J9OIg605X0P7rUm5B9jHdpBuFNdofWEFWR4Y7loIS3YHTnEtRAkc6lqAgtkUuMSi/QvII2xNV6Nq4jhgWJoOKsbuwHWuhbDgMeT+rzufIYEH1FNWBJ5As7wkvI907Zk0g0VTYJtIjCpzgmsBLDiCzlBW8Ou+2LAQ2r7pZ3HNNqRUVoCFl1xyCYCngY2B1dN2VBH6o7XgA64FMdAPuBrVm+0E1gAeAsa7FiRnrgW2tGh/EHBDlgG7mgqJbwiMzdJZRXgLWA2Y5lqQGE4HjnItRMk8DGzgWogcOQv4P8trHgVeR8uDa0mhb5GFBXmJByDF9ZneyJF2q2tB2jCUHjmOHcIAFCv7oGtBcuBQ7FLlIlZAxmRz4NvAd4A+6LSBmUk66OpxVMdANL+uw1RtKJrqV40rgL1dC+GIN9ADO8O1IBnYE7iqgH7PAH6Cql60pee+62to36wOjHQtQAu+QOcqK8jCHOdaiIx8qaB+f4j8LzvHNeppYUF7s+NRMIXvfAG407UQTYwBPu9aCMfMRYdOPedakJR8Ebit4DF+hXYRFqBVZNMH1McNn2adURTfICgr6JnzeRvxdhSlVCSH0yaeoNnp1MyjwLbA4OJkKoXB6E3+mGM5utE2zlKO5agKw5CVesm1ICmZg10xtTQMRfv0862X42KHfX4LNnMidmUli+Bo6rHEyJMTXQuQgUuA50sY58v08Cm1s7AggdYCPl2wUEWzFPK8jTE1LIgBwF9QbdrAPFZBXvwnXAuSkkXRLHQ6MKvxMwcZhzyTaDYH7qOx5m/ldGpmKPBUjoO7YgaK4nrdwdi/Aw52MK4PjEdRUD7SjbY/o/pLH6Hi4X2A5VAC+yrAFqhO05IZxnocWBfiLSwoaqgvykbwmV7oi7yp5HE/A/yh5DF9YhkUDF+0E6cI5iKrOrvHz3QUIPIMimT6K6ovPA69nAakGKs/8CrwsMnCgt4MzwLLphioaqwJ/K/E8W7EsK8W4B00+5nkWpCS2BdVpbCdNo8FPpvkomnASbZSVZSRJY61C0FZk7AEdkW2fecytA892fK6jYCNkljYiMeBtS0HqSJbo720onkEWK+EcerCMNxvv5XJ+ighwoYRpjVsMxOpR1jdqsCFBY9xGHBAwWPUjQHAla6FKJE3Gn9uZXHNNBuFfQo5n4o83asMBqMtq6LqPy2OgiT6FNR/XRmK8pifdS1IifwXZf70Sth+lu3C93jL9lVlBMUFUxyH6ksF7PE5mCINbwJ3W7RfzsbCglzLg9B2hc8shVzyeQdTrI7S57py7rdTWBHtlT/kWpASGYr2ahORJiJjJHrYfec40u2JxTGCoKxZOR5YzLUQJfKWTeM0CvsK9ciZ7U2+U/wtUG3aQDZWRIncncKiFm0/TBvzOBp/My2aOYT86gx12vqrSI4GhrgWoiSGWrSdmlZhZ1OfnNk8FG0f7KrnBeJZBPfZYks0fopmc4u2E7NkFVxA9cuJJmE4sGuG67sI1rUI9gc+53D831D80S9fRjWukjIhaxpQXbZ5sijc0dh96YHkuJrFbYb8EUNQRlHicEBLbCuiPJhVYW8BrsnYRxUYRrrzX/rTWQ6SstkWVSksm982/X115Gj9Zs5jXIaSUWy4NY9E27pY2eNRKqHtNYsXIEtgHmVb2dG0PkLlIuB+7JxE7bgG+wPoHgAetw2caMWb6OiJTbJ25Ji+aJsraUW8YcD5xYkTaLAc8C6qulA0myHfTDtWAr6HjrV5DvtjNHdCkU0bpZBtNDDWJlsnjqVRDKjvRcZsSnBeB+xWqDSBiKnIT/B2wePYnib4PLKWtwFPogSZKKioC+nFamhqvz/p4/BfbfQzMy+FBfgBql7uO5dhDoAYTvnVKzqds4EjC+x/NJanobdgGsrCmYNmnQPIJ2b9+8A5YK7pZMt/sV9IV5GtgLtiPn+Qeh3s5AtrI0uWNzsAfy+g3zy4n6btrTyru0F9KgfEVdg4jKCsriiqMPx+BfWbldloKv0xeTidmnmKepwzOxh4ERXOamZJtGapw2FhPrImmt2kPhC5DTejdeZKOfeblT2Ae5v/I28LC/XZ5hnBgrWEf0o9itH5TBFRZTPRLsclBfSdlgNocfhz3hYWdALeQPyfNvZDzoMowXgNOvNc16oxAHljizhn9lrk+S36GA4T+9Dm5ZG30yliRTRt8T2vcSawMirBeTnwVbfiBBoUfc7sMkhhdiio/3a8CWzHgkuxjynCwoI2ukFH8/lMN9r7ewX4o2NZ8uBGdPzmho7lyEpftM9Z1LGP7wOXAreiIIf+BY3TzO/R8aixp1MUZWGhPufMTkQvoDoE+G+KIoZmkbzwV1X5EAW5TChhrM1QzPjwAvq+ER3mnMiRVpSFBUUNTaO4E6vLoi+KWPGdf6LgANDLdCt3ouTCQiiy7roSxnoZ+S/Obfy9F/Iopw2KeAoFQnwdHeWSuKh4kRY24h78P5unDnwObcKDypI8gwrq+c7mwL8djNsHFYrfGG03LY/inpdhXtmX91DNpoloWfUfJOvLaQctQ2G3QWuBgDsuAA7s8X8HAec5kCVv7sB/X0liipwSR0xAZ8z6fs6sr8wCvoKWJ808jNZkhb+xC2YV9LuMdy1IGRQRONGKugRT+MiptC+Y57puUl7Upb6YkTIsLGgevzhhLVs2r6CKDR+2+fxZlNfre8JGkcEUlaKMNWxEnc6Z9YWDMCfZr0M9To0rOpiiEpRlYWHeadVlR490Kg+gzCITk9C21cbFilM4UXmfMo4SdUaZFjbiCYIDqgy2R0XykrAMmv30K0yacpiLMsXKCKZwQpkWNmIisFfZg3YYN2GXO/o+WuduV4w4pdGFXj7XuhakKFxYWNCbf1sXA3cIm5CuyPtT5FMV0DVbYneMozeUta3Tk7pUpqgi55P+RIa6bI/U5fdYABdTYlAVuMHA+i4GrzGzUJWCd1Je/wSyTr4nbAxBgRRPOJYjd1xZWKjPObNV4mTsa+X2pC5BLnUJCpkPVxYWZAUWxv+skarwErA37YMkbPpZFQVU+MyyyJl2j2tB8sSV0ymiTlkjrjmQ+Kr1NqyCppTdOfXnindQMMWbrgXJC5cWFmQN3iHbcY8Bpc19L8f+pqKX6RY59umCRYFPUN2aw9a4trAR9+N/pI1LdkAJ6nnSG81+BubcrwuGUY/wS6dOp2Zq6SAoiavJX1lBydd1Oai6Lr+H8ylxxHPAuvifNeKCvShujfYQWq4MKKj/shgKjCX/AuSlUxULC8HKpuFsijlrppm6bPPUIpiiKhYWlDWyFP6fM1sWk1ElifcLHucZVBR+jYLHKZqBqMj9w64FyUKVLCwoYH2KayE8YRQW1fYyUhcrOwLPi9tXycKCrMUH+J81UjRPUe6Ja2+gioCfLXHMIlgCpeDd4VqQtFRlW6cndckaKYq9gatKHnN5lDO7eMnj5s0clDP7omtB0lA1CxvxFlqfBRbkNrKfFJ6GGcg6beNg7DxZmPIKkOdOVS0s6MHsmHqzFmxGjzNDS6QLhSzW4dgSl99jaqrmdGqmLo6OPPkTbh+yj1CWVR3wMpiiqlNi0HEGn8T/rJG8mINyXXsWBC+bx9HMZ2XHcmTlk8hXUvQ+dq5U2cKC3PAfuBaiIoymOo6Susx+RroWwJYqW1hQ1sgiqApCJ/MqCkGsysvrRXTU4zquBcnIcugo0ftcC5KUKjudIhZD0TaVF7RAvkP1Dq5aDTmgulwLkpEp6HcpKwglE1W3sCCrMh3YxbUgjngQOMS1EC2YjHJNP+9akIwshvJmi8h4yh0fLGzEWGBD10I4YDjVTcDui4Ip+rsWJAfWxgMHVNWdTs10YjbP9VRXWUEzH5uC5VXGi20enyws6AHupHIyvlRKGEc9tt9sjjdxgk8WFuqznZCEX+OHskJ97kvlrawPTqdmJqLylb5njZiYhmKp33MtSEKeRvdkddeCZGQlFLDziGtB2uGbhQW9BdNWtveFUfhXmrMuPoYRyGtcSXyzsCCrM5f6HqY1HtjHtRApeA3VfvLdk78kCgO9y7UgrfDN6RTRhaZhvk/BWrEvcLlrIVIyEAW59HYtSEZmoWCKrMee5I6PFjbibeDLroXImTuBo1wLkYF3G39u7VSK7HQjS3uDa0F64quFjbiTesUZbwGMcS1ERrrRtN73E/Ag/Tm7heGj06mZumwnAFyC/8oKCiWtRUlR4BjXAvTEd4W9G7jUtRA58CH18bKCEu3rcGpc5Uqi+q6woAd9rmshMnIqMMG1EDnj+wvoSSoYdumz0yliCsoa2dy1ICl5HeW6znEtSM48D6wFfNq1ICk5FFWkqBR1sLCgk8ffcC1ESn6OKhLWEV99DLeiQ8YqRx0sLMBs9NDv7FoQSx5Cyel15W20J7uZa0Es2RdV+agcdbGwAL+jYi74BPzEtQAlcAKKgvKF3wL/cS1EO+qksOCXo+NqKp7KlRM+nTM7g4rLWjeF/SdwjWshEuLTyyUrv6eCWyQtGEXFfSF1U1jwQxHOxoNyJDlTdQfUc2h7rdLUxenUTNXPmZ1COee6Vo2qnzN7BPCoayFM1NHCgrZKproWog0n4UlJzQKoqpUdg0JDK08dLSxU95zZss91rRpVPWf2W8ALroVIQl0tLMAZVC9SZaRrASrAz5mXhlcFrsCjA57ramEjqnTOrKtzXatG1c6Z3QOPlih1trAAV1Kdt2dV128uOA05oVxTFTkSU3eFBfiZawGAi/Dw8OAC+Qj3ObOT0L6rV3SCwt4D/Nnh+HMIa9dWXIrymV3xczysvtkJCgtuz5k9heqc61o1XC0THgPOcTR2JurudIqYiptzZl8B9qY657pWjRdRIEXZ58weAvyv5DFzoVMsLMDpyGtcJifSeRFNthyP1rRl8Q/guhLHy5VOsbCgnNm5lBdMMRb4bklj+cxkdEZrWefM7otf6X7z0UkWFsoNphhZ0jh1YBQ6N6lo/oBepN7SSRY2YhKwZ8FjXE8FC3hVmNlo6TC8wDHeR0E0VYqysqbTLCzAX4B/FTxGCJKw51yKzZY5mYqWfbGhExUWilUon851rRpF5TK/gAe5rknoxCkxaLtlCLBezv2+g8778eVc16rxNLAx+R9ydiR+VLww0qkWFhQal3ct4JMof+uobuQdSnovCg2tBZ1qYUHBFIuiA6jy4Gm0ZRDIxuvke87sAdToVIVOtrCg7YS8HBGug9nrxAnks6wow8FYKp1sYUEhg+8Cu2Ts5078Pte1akxHh3Z/MWM/e1KzJUqnW1iA88i+mR62cfLnVHQ+T1rOpHoVRzITFFZkUbi6nOtaNbKcM/s2NQ1cCQor0gaEz8WPOsi+kvac2ZOobtXMTASFnUcaxRtNjTyQFcX2vjyJCrXXkk53OjUzEViW5CU430BOjbqd61o1bM+ZreS5rnkRLOz82JTgPIH6nutaNZL6GCp7rmteBAs7PzOAD4FtDe0eAb5dvDiBBm8DfYFNDe32Q2GntSVY2AU5DRhvaBMcTeVjCvu8ALi/JFmcESxsa+IKkP+NkJzuglmNnx1bfDYbFQT3rgqiLcHCtibu+IYQJOGOXwFPtPj/k4GXS5bFCUFh29Nq2vsbtH4NuKPnfZkE/MKFIC4ICtueMcDFTf+eTk2jZzzjGuCWpn+fTAd564PCxtMcGjcK7b0G3BMtS54HfulSkLIJTqd4pgAro8oUw1EoYsA9rwKbANcC/3YsS6l0DRq0omsZqs7SaA/wJdeCBOZjCZQg0FHleLpdC+ABk/Ho/NAOovZbOK0Ia9hAwCOCwgYCHhEUNhDwiKCwgYBHBIUNBDwiKGwg4BFBYQMBjwgKGwh4RFDYQMAjgsIGAh4RFDYQ8IigsIGARwSFDQQ8IihsIOARQWEDAY8IChsIeERQ2EDAI4LCBgIeERQ2EPCIUNOpPV20f6F1oQqKoYqi/8TdZ4CPqNB9Dha2PTuiqnyvAC/2+JkDnO5OtECOrInOUprEgvf5A+Cv7kRbkGBh29O78ecKbT5fuixBAoXSC+gX8/lyJcmRiGBh22OaBn1UihSBojHdx0rd56CwgYBHBIUNBDwiKGwg4BFBYQMBjwgKGwh4RFDYQMAjgsIGAh4RFDYQ8IigsIGARwSFDQQ8IihsIOARQWEDAY8IChsIeETS9LqFgQ2BocCSjeveByYDjwFPFSJdPCsAn2n8uTh6+bwPTAEeB/7rQKaIvsDngVVQmt4sYFpDpoccydQH3cOVgSWARYDZDbmeBR5u/NslA5h3T/uie/oees4eB/7nTrTMfALYGPgk+v6j3+0t9N0/n6QTk8JuChwJbI+Uoh2TgJuBXzcGL4r1gW8BOwCrG9pOAm4F/gjcWaBMzewCHA5sRfvvdirwN+BU4ImC5VkW2B/YA9gA5X624z3gPuAq4DJgesGyRXwaOAgYDnzK0HYScDvwJ+AfBcuVFzsB30fPxKIx7V4EbgB+hV6gLekaNGjFVv8/BLgCvRFsuRv4GqrUkBdfBM4C1k15/QTgMOxu8h7A1TGfXwgc0Pj7Z9CDvqqlXFcC3yB/y9YPOBv4ZsrrPwR+CfwUzVqKYAPgXNI9YwBvAMcg5c3CMGBczOdjgC1S9Lsh0iHbZwL0LB1Ii5dmqzXsnsg8p/0itwBeBr6U8vpm+gG3ALeRXllB05C/IwVcOLtYgB5qgEPQNDfNjdkbeAEYnJNMoBnIFNIrK+g7+gGaDeyZg0zNdAEXAw+S/hkDTZsvQsuMIZmlypejgLGkeyYA9gImIqWfj54Kuw/S7jy4Fk0R07IFmgJtm484gKzmS+Rzg19AS4bfZuxnAHA/sExWgYBLgAty6CeiF3oefpdTf6ug73+/nPoD1WR6nnwMRB78hHzqffUG/oNmAB/TrLBrorVLnvyZdDVxvgLchRwjeTMQrR3XzNjPZsA52cUBpLRZv/tb0VKkCA4GrsnYxzrIGq6UXZyWXIumkS7ZHhiVY3/RbORjmhX25ISdzEUOiiSlH/sBP0rYb8R2wF8sr7GlD9mr4W0PrJddlI/ZDvh6ymuvALbJUZZW7A6cn/LaAcAdyFNaJH9EcrrilITtPkQ6lKRe1Dpo2QXMU9ihmKcUk9H6qD/yPi7f+Pdkw3U2a6CBpFPWd9H0Oanz5l3g2BTjNLMQegPmyZEprvkRWgvb8B76vmZZXncAct7ZciX2U/5pwNvY1wS+HE29y2Y42sWI43lgN6Q/y6Dn/ceobG4ce0V/iRR2K8MF0xvCXIT2jd5HX+ZFwFro5rdjCPIIJuG3aI8qCTeit+lg5IBYEb1M1gV+iDzDrRjXkOmGhOPYcCPwVfSdDEYPzs7AvxJevz7me9HMGsBpCds+j7achqLvaSB66Q5D3uC4e9jMmdj5AH4AbJ6w7d1oOTQI3dMBDVm3Ql75JMq7KPI+l43pd3wa3a8bkDNvJvJ0nw5sYrh2ExpLy0hhTftfZyBnQSsmoj3FOFYzfA56sHdN0O4RpAi7Atchj/R7qOjzVLTBfiby0B3E/NOO85FSmGYFtoxDD/GuyJo81ZDrBeAm5Dj7csK+knwHEccnbPcj5Cn/NXpwpqNp2Tso8GUUUowzEvTVCyl4EvoBxyVoNxnYsvFzNdoSnIksz1vIn3EAesHclaC/Hcnm8EyDyScyivaW9GHi/SGLoZfYx5v7cRvqAK8aPr8RbYBHD0JEFzL/SaI4/i9Bm8uBfRO0izgfudfHoTV60gfNhpvR5riJa5DSxu3tAmyUcNy1SPZdbIccUkk4Cr0QLzG0OxCt154ztDsYc8H1Z9DvPC2BfG8ja/sH4NuGtoej57Is4oIiQIERcVwOLAW8yfxGprvR9+ToH2CeDm0LnBfz+TNk89ANA7Y2tLkNO2WNeAy96d9Lca2Jl9EULinXIGWI29YYhuSdauhrL8PnoL3YpMoacSmaLpum2nthdrLsY/h8JnLeJVHWZr6DLM4OMW22Adam+GiyCJNR2wlN+dtxb+MnlmhKbAon3BNZq7ydLBFJpi+HZuj/HTRlzpuTsY8E+oPh88XR2s3EzobPr0fbamk4HbjH0MZ0z9alxx5iC44mYQxtCw5j/tlcK5LMfPLiccPnPwZOyDpIpLD3YH7LHQDMQPtdh5F9H7MZ06L7PGB8juPlwUz0XdgyBvNDupTh8wHI3R/HLxNL1JqzDJ8PQ8uddmxmuP4VsgWdTMC8zZR0eZEHdyRoczyKQrsY6dMQ20EihZ2C9rBMLIa2f85Bm+Avo8ia/Wh/aFQSGUxv4utS9l0kDyKHWxpeMHzex/D5usT7HcaT7AGK4x9ozdiO3sS/NEwvlBsxb2eYMEXlZQlnteUxkj2n/ZC+nI9e3OORPu2BMuFiaQ6cOA6zE6EnK6G92IuB11G2x1ct+1iBeGWfgUL3qkaW5AaTopucgAMNn+eRWjgDeMDQpmXmSAPTtH6snTgteYL4vfdBxM8C8uaHaOZlw+poxno1Mpy3EBOO26yws5BHcYrlgM1sgrxdr6J80CQsTnya3+vkvw2TB1myWLKup0171a9l7D/C9FKKswgma/G6pSytmIhmee34BPFpoXkzgXhHmIkupKy3IIu9Rs8GPYP/J6D9ujEZBgVZgDEkiyYy5eRmnTYVRZZjCLNW+jBlHOX1nWXpp6z7auonr+yspNyFYgCeydjPOihhfz5Pe6sHZyrKlNkFbbJn4WQU6RKHaQqxJOV/6UkoymOeBFNIYV5WxdRPnLKYttH6WsrSim7iLflc7KeoeTABBSMdQPaZxGU0xUfHven/hsLYNkLJ0GnLc5xBfJD8FOJv7kCSRUp1Em8ZPl85p3FMVT3i5DDJOMROlJasTPxaeSpul1MXoud3a7TTYQqeaMf5NAJQkkzNHkRB6WsiJ8PXkWe4XaxuK34c89lkzNOHrSzG6gRM20Lrk93Krgx8ztAm7hmIW1uCOVAmCSY/yXiKCZix5XYU7DEETZcPRr6epNZ3KRozVdu11GsoUufAxsCDgZGYp2g7IXd2O8YZrt8/iXAdxKPEe5qXJlkkVBwmb/8ryDHSDpNnf2fkL8mCKRHeFMzgggkoeGZfZH2HkiyvenfI7vx4GUVvbEB81MkSxG9im7JZNiEobTOzMG+5HEv6tf/SmPOY7yM+e+YB4l/kXag6Q1p2w5wDfFuG/sviaVSkbbih3VrAqt0olvNAFoyF7IM2zkditqBPolS7uHjiuLXGTSjSKs6BcB4qmZFmj3EHZJXy2EqoCn8lPrNnVVTaxRQk34oLMeevmpIY3kD3dY+YNgei6aJttY3+xMe2g3wjZVVW3AsldvTcTuuHpuVJEtv/Dvyb+Gn+ct3oxsYlmV+H+W0O5rjOOKag6neHx7TpbsixFXa1fY9BX9g4VIOpqCqAZXMlMJr4IIqD0BruCIt+r8Kc4jehMb6Ji4hXWFCywRySFy4YiEJpTaWHLsY+qSAt69N+CTIbfQ9JjIVJh7oWQk6lOL6fYKB+mG+MKbrnDMwVI/oiec9GoXFxrI1ubPR2Ww9N4csMVyuS2ZjjfUEvwYfR9xHHFijSLUmFkDMTtAGFHybZ078KvbBNjrLvI0/rEEO7D0guYx48GfNZL+C7CfpYG+UDx/FWN7JWL9G+1ObXkHv8e20+XxpFZsSFgE3HHIr2EgqPTFJx7giUvfMPtP59DT3AfZE3ezdax7Iug6bG+5O9nm0V+AXy2pteQusjB8xDKMXvWbQ/2RvlMe9Ji6iaNtyPXUWHY9FUz8Q30LN2M/BPdE/nIg/pJg0ZTbm1ESNIv4WShruQdWznM/gZCvVsV+hhDTQljuNp4JnuxkCXEO8AOAzlff4JPfAfIKv6RTR3N0W13Eyy/bBfNPrcMUHbRVBwR5rKAhchr9uXUlxbNQ4keVzuBiQv19OOgyzb34P8ICMTtF2Y9Pc04i6SFxTMi5fRlD7Osz4a+RMuRjENH6EKGjuRLJzxGpinaKPRje8fc0F/4vdT40hadwikRA+jN3+RJH1bV50HkZW92NQwB/YgfvrXjhPQ9oVtYogtL6LZlQtOwvz7rUqyF1dPptKY4kfbOu8y79iJvDkWOyfRbFQRvsg9tBtId/xCVbkEe8tnyz6ky/9tvt7kWc7CS8BnKc/R1JMnSVdRMgmH0Igca96HvZn8C1Gfhqy3LTPQuiyJJ9KWc3D3Fi6S81GmR97JEu+iiKcrcujrK5gL9qXhdhS7m7TyY1H8hmx7y604lCY96Bk4cRl6S5niQE18hCI5js7Yz1eRcmVJ+YuYgaJrkni9wW1wf1r+hRxreZVwvRSts/LMRz4GVaMwhS4m5XAU5mhbYzkpts/BKWhZlzWFciryGs9XlaNVpNNYdJOOxf7Iwdlort0PxUrmwQ1ovXkw6er/TEG/y1JoIz8pphuVRaGL7Ptd9JLbGPsCbBF/Qd72/Sgm2+VetCuxH+lK/0xDZUOXRKVbs1DEi/l69LydjX18wlT0UluWFkXb2h03GRF57b6EbuBA5qW7zWl0/jpyOd/cELSoN13E+sw773Rl9Iv1Ri+f2cgb/SqqRnAd2nJKw/JotjGTBXNf+6CtkbSVHT6NHBAzevx/Fypp+QDZZzkRK6Cp6JYodjc6AHthZAWmoXv4LFLwayl/HbgO2rbZCCnycuiedqHnaTKKXX4S7e3egv2JAO3oiwJqYEHl6o22l7Icwt0bff/DUfbTAOYdQD4bGZTod7sebWm1zbX+f8fhAJS4v8JUAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1>The mask-image Property</h1>

<h3>An image with a mask layer image:</h3>
<div class="mask1">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg" 
       alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
</div>

<h3>Original image:</h3>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg" 
     alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
```

Comment: You are correct there is an error message about the CORS policy. And converting it to a base64 image worked. 
Thank you this solved my problem.

Comment: @DavidNelson Glad to have helped, if you can mark my answer as accepted it would help me too :) Thanks!